# Cakephp App.base and $this->here

Tags: php, cakephp

There are similar questions here but they have not the answer to my problem.

My app folder is below dev/, so I put the line

```
Configure::write('App.base', '/');
```

in the bootstrap.php to get the links work without 'dev' in the url.

But in one form I refer to `$this->here` as the action and it has an extra slash at the begining like `//admin/controller...`

How can I avoid the extra slash?

Answer (score 2):

`Configure::write('App.base', '');`

I actually stumbled upon your (old) question while trying to fix some $this->here issues on a shared host, and your question actually helped me solve my problem. So, thanks.

But in case you're still looking for an answer a year later, the above works.